# Js standard object(An Array with string as key) as ajax post data is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an associative array

```
var order = [];
order['id'] = 1266;
order['customer'] = [];
order['customer']["firstName"] = "John";
order['customer']["lastName"] = "Doe";
order['customer']["age"] = 46;
```

I want to send this array as data into my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
     url : 'http:example.com',
     method : 'post',
     dataType : 'json',
     data : order,
     success : function() {
     }
})
```

**Ajax are calling my url properly but sending empty data. I have tried**

1. JSON.stringify(order)
2. data : {'order' : order}
3. data : {'order' : JSON.stringify(order)}

But none of these are working

Comment: You should be using objects, not arrays

Comment: [Don't use arrays with non-integer properties](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)!

Comment: Thank you a lot for https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/ article that properly clarify me why we should not use associative array.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change the array to object. Instead of  `var order = [];` use `var order = {};`

Comment: He should be using an object for this too: `order['customer'] = {};`

Comment: yeh, I got it. Thanks